# Fourier series - Integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, fourier-series

> Let $f$ be a complex-valued piecewise continuous function defined on the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$ and let 
>   \begin{equation}
> \frac{a_{0}}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[a_{n}\cos(nx)+b_{n}\sin(nx) \right]
> \end{equation}
>   denote its Fourier series on $[-\pi,\pi]$. Determine the value of 
>   \begin{equation}
> \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}| f(x+\pi)-f(x)|^{2}dx
> \end{equation}
>   in terms of $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$.

I realize that this question will have to deal with Parseval's identity, however, I don't know how to use this fact to answer the question.

Comment: try to  write a few terms  in integral part,for example what would be $cos(x+\pi)$ and  $sin(x+\pi)$

Answer (score 1):

The question should have specified that $f$ is considered to be periodic with period $2\pi$ (otherwise your integrand is undefined for $x > 0$).

Start by substituting $x+\pi$ for $x$ in the Fourier series and simplifying.

Comment: does there exist special formula for this?i mean existed formula already,i dont remember exactly

Answer (score 0):

i will try to  use few term for demonstration,let us use $n=2$

so we have

$f(x)=a_0/2+a_1*cos(x+\pi)+b_1*sin(x+\pi)+a_2*cos(2*x+2*pi)+b_2*sin(2*x+2*\pi)$

now you see that $cos(x+2*\pi)=cos(x)$ and  $sin(x+2*\pi)=sin(x)$

both are periodic  with $2*\pi$
if we consider this fact we would have

$f(x)=a_0/2+a_1*cos(x+\pi)+b_1*sin(x+pi)+a_2*cos(2*x)+b_2*sin(2*x)$

if we subtract  this from original function,we get

$f(x)=a_0/2+a_1*cos(x+\pi)+b_1*sin(x+\pi)+a_2*cos(2*x)+b_2*sin(2*x)$

-$(a_0/2+a_1*cos(x)+b_1*sin(x)+a_2*cos(2*x)+b_2*sin(2*x))$

can you  square this  ?please cancel also term $a_0/2$ and  consider fact that $cos(x+\pi)=-cos(x)$ and  $sin(x+\pi)=-sin(x)$

Comment: Use Parsevel's theorem to get sum of squares.